# Visual Studio Code How to lint only changed file?

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code, linter

Is there any configuration in visual studio code that only lint changed the file (python, javascript, CSS)?. I don't want to lint existing/unmodified file. I just to want lint the code which I have written.

Note. used flake8 and eslint for linting

Answer (score 1):

for vs code, if we can enable lint on save,

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

then we will only lint changed file
or we can use scripts like

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB master | grep -E "(.js$|.ts$)"`

https://gist.github.com/seeliang/0f0de424d1cdc4541c338f4ee93b7e6a

Answer (score 0):

The Python extension only lints opened files, but it won't distinguish between unmodified or dirty files.